# I want to compare two values similar to contains function in apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

I have fetched field value on account I want to compare the values like contains function

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{
    Opportunity opp{set;get;}
    public string Customergrp; 


    public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {   

        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        opp.AccountId =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
        opp.Master_Account__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
        Customergrp = [select Customer_Group_Trio__c from Account where id = :opp.AccountId limit 1].Customer_Group_Trio__c;  
    }
    public PageReference save()
    { 
        if(Customergrp.IndexOf(opp.Customer_Group_ERP__c) != -1)
        {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Customer_Group_ERP__c Mismatch');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;  

        }
    }
}
```

Customergrp - "6220 - UNASSIGNED CUSTOMER" and Customer_Group_ERP__c - "6119".

If both the values don't match first four digit it should throw error.

Comment: Don't forget to vote if it working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Apex strings do have a contains method, unlike a lot of programming languages.  You use it like so:

**Syntax**

**contains(substring)**

Returns **true** if and only if the String that called the method **contains** the specified sequence of characters in **substring**.
Signature

```
public Boolean contains(String substring)
```

Parameters

> **substring** - Type: **String**
>
> **Return Value** - Type: **Boolean**

**Solution**

```
Boolean result=Customergrp.contains(opp.Customer_Group_ERP__c);
```

It returns **true** if the sequence of characters appears in the String.

You need to change the **Save()** function as below mentioned

```
public PageReference save() { 
if(Customergrp.contains(opp.Customer_Group_ERP__c)){
   ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Customer_Group_ERP__c Mismatch');
   ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
   return null;  
 }   
}
```

Comment: Your code could be shortened here. If you're testing a boolean, you don't need to explicitly check to see if it's true or false. `if(result == true)` could be replaced with `if(result)`. Since the boolean result isn't being used anywhere else, you could skip assigning the result of `String.contains()`, and just use it directly in the `if()` like `if(Customergrp.contains(opp.Customer_Group_ERP__c))`